# Android FCM Notification not getting in some Android devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

When I implement the FCM Notifications for Android app. I am not getting the notifications in some Android devices like Mi, Oppo, One Plus Two etc. in Mi getting refreshed token but not getting the notification and Oppo or One Plus Two not getting the refreshed token and notifications. How can I fix this problem? Thanks...

Comment: Can you please post some code here?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MainActivity.java

Comment: please see the above url i implement from FCM from above url..

Comment: Can you check and verify it please there is changing in Android version O for FCM notifications?

Comment: If you are getting this for OREO then this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52849445/some-oreo-devices-are-not-getting-push-notification/52894271#52894271) will help you

Answer (score 0):

Check your android manifest file. It should be like this

```
<service
        android:name="yourFireBaseMessagingServiceClass"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Raman Dhiman

Form Android version Oreo, there are changes for setting notification in the notification manager. For that, you have to [create and manage notification channel](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) to set a notification in notification manager.

For setting Firebase notification, check out below two links:

1. [Firebase Cloud Messaging:](https://medium.com/globallogic-latinoamerica-mobile/firebase-cloud-messaging-warning-updating-to-android-oreo-1343fe894bd5) Warning updating to Android Oreo. In your case, you will get an error in your log cat as well as also in your device notification toast message (only if developer option is on)
2. How to create and manage [firebase push notification for android oreo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java)

I think you will get resolve your issue from this information.