# Firebase push notifications are not received on Samsung devices running Android 7.0+

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM according to [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).
I do get the messages while the app is in the background or foreground state, or even if it is swiped out of the *recent apps* screen.

The problem is, that on Samsung S8, messages are not received at all when the app is in the background. (other devices do not have this issue).

To add to the confusion, this problem takes places only with the *RELEASE* build version of the app. With debug build version everything works as expected.

If you have encountered something similar, please share your experience.

**UPDATE**

The problem might be that SHA-1 fingerprint for the RELEASE certificate is not stored in the project in Firebase. It is easy to forget to put it there during development.

Comment: hey any solution for your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't figured that out.

Comment: Any changes in this? :(

Comment: @Maury Nope. :-(

Comment: @Maury I've updated the question.

Comment: please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276126/android-fcm-notification-not-getting-in-some-android-devices/54326107#54326107