# Some Oreo devices are not getting Push Notification

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

Samsung `S8/S5/J2/Note3` are getting `Firebase Push Notification` successfully either app is killed, in background or foreground,

but `Infinix Note 5 (Android One- Oreo)` and `Oppo F9(Oreo)` are not getting push notification if app is killed, they work fine if app is in background or foreground.

I went through a lot of articles, [this](https://hackernoon.com/notifications-in-android-are-horribly-broken-b8dbec63f48a) and [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-your-push-notifications-never-see-the-light-of-day-3fa297520793), mentions that Chinese phones haves this problem, and there are some work around from user side to make these notification work on their phones.

but i want to know if anything is possible from development side to make notification work on each and every android device.

I am targeting  API 27, and this is my code

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService  extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {


  @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
        Map data = remoteMessage.getData();

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        Set<String> keys = remoteMessage.getData().keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            try {
                jsonObject.put(key, remoteMessage.getData().get(key));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        message= jsonObject.getString("message");

         sendNotification(message, urlToOpen);



    private void sendNotification(final String msg, final String urlToOpen) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.notification_channel_general);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                        .setContentTitle("App Name")
                        .setContentText(msg)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "App Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

**Gradle**

```
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.app"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        // Disable fabric build ID generation for debug builds
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
}

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
```

Answer (score 13):

**Source** : [Enable background services and Jobs (or FCM) in Chinese ROMs](https://medium.com/mindorks/enable-background-services-in-chinese-roms-32e73dfba1a6)

> Infinix Note 5 (Android One- Oreo) and Oppo F9(Oreo) are not getting push notification if app is killed, they work fine if app is in background or foreground.

Chinese ROMs using (Oxygen OS, MIUI etc) when the apps are swiped from the recent app tray your app gets terminated ( similar to Force Stop). And due to this every task running in the background like Services, Jobs gets killed with the app. Even High priority FCM doesn’t see the daylight in Chinese ROMs

> Real time problems :

1) You can’t fetch location of the user. So, no app would work properly if it depends on real-time location

2) You can’t recevie the FCM high priority notifications

3) No time specific task/Job would execute if app is not in the tray and many more ….

> Solution

user needs to enable auto start in settings for app to keep background service/Job running.By default it is off.To do this in some of the devices we can use,

**Sample code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent();

        String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;

        switch (manufacturer) {

            case "xiaomi":
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter",
                        "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
                break;
            case "oppo":
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                        "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));

                break;
            case "vivo":
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager",
                        "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
                break;
        }

      List<ResolveInfo> arrayList =  getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
              PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nilesh, Is it possible to launch this component on Infinx device? The infinix device i am testing on, contains Android One (Oreo 8.1) OS.

Comment: @TahaKirmani sorry to say i have no idea about `Infinx device` but have u added ` android:stopWithTask="false"` in your `FirebaseMessagingService` like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123197/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated/51129304#51129304

Comment: I am getting the error "     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.coloros.safecenter/.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity } from ProcessRecord{54211b 26708:com.platute.app/u0a142} (pid=26708, uid=10142) requires oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE" even though I have addded oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE in the Android Manifest

Comment: But this is not working in all the vivo series and oppo series because its says "Activity not found" while trying to open setting screen.

Answer (score 6):

In the Oreo, they introduce one new concept of channelization of push notification. You can read more about channelization [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels). Implement the notification for Oreo and above the bellow ore separately. You can refer the following answer to [fix the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645550/push-notification-issue-in-oreo-8-0?answertab=active#tab-top).

I have fixed the issue in xamarin.android, hope this will work for you.

Comment: @K K: Thanks, but I am already using channels in push notifications

Comment: And still it is not working? R u receiving the notifications? Have u checked?

Comment: @K K, I am receiving notifications in samsung devices, but not on Chinese devices. Chinese devices do get notification if app is opened or in background.

Comment: This is the Issue with the custom OS, In fact, I face this issue in the OnePlus. Have you tried on a OnePlus device?

Answer (score 5):

This is the issue with all the chinese devices.Once you have killed the app...it is removed from memory and not all active ...but in case of the other device makers this is not the case ..they will not remove the app completely from the memory. I too faced this issue with xiaomi devices ....they have an option to lock the app ,which keeps app in memory even if its killed to clear ram memory

Answer (score 4):

Since oreo there is new `Notification Channels` implementation ([started in Android 8.0 (API level 26)](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels))

so you have to create the channel using below code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "News Channel";
            String description = "Default Notification News Channel";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getAppContext().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
```

and override notification builder as below

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getAppContext(),CHANNEL_ID);
```

assuming you have CHANNEL_ID value something you want

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "DEFAULT_NEWS_CHANNEL";
```

this is already tested with OnePlus3T device so it should work for you

Answer (score 3):

I hope the following code will work for you. Its working for me in every devices.

```
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreenActivity.class);

        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence nameChannel = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
            String descChannel = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(context.getString(R.string.app_name), nameChannel, importance);
            channel.setDescription(descChannel);
            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            assert notificationManager != null;
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity((context), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Create Notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setChannelId(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentTitle(TextUtils.isEmpty(title) ? getString(R.string.app_name) : title)
                .setContentText(description)
                .setTicker(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 500})
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        if (result != null) {
            notification.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(result));
        }

        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify(100, notification.build());
```

I just have created Notification Channel, Check If condition for Oreo.

Let me know if you get any problem. I am here to help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and after searching and working around,
I have found that user need to enable autostart and battery optimization permission manually
for more details refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50291806/7579041) link

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer if this solves your issue