# oppo, vivo app kill notification not coming in android fcm

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Testing app in motorola , samsung working fine when app is killed. but when i test app in vivo, oppo not working in case of app is destroyed.

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        //  handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Android Manifest xml:

```
 <service
        android:name="notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="notification.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I am not getting message in case of vivo, oppo any help would be recommended.

Comment: in the case of vivo, oppo what is their android os version ?

Comment: @Arpan os is oreo.

Comment: Difference is that motorola and Samsung is just clearing the app from "Recents" it's background service is still running one of which is FCM service. While "vivo" & "oppo" force closes the app closing all the background service as well so its FCM service is also closed which handles the custom Notification for the app.

Comment: @Harish i had the same problem check this my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/52943903/7666442

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod i will try this but not getting in oppo phone.

Comment: @nitinkumarp how to start again background service for these app

Answer (score 11):

> Infinix Note 5 (Android One- Oreo) and Oppo F9(Oreo) are not getting
>   push notification if app is killed, they work fine if app is in
>   background or foreground.

Chinese ROMs using (Oxygen OS, MIUI etc) when the apps are swiped from the recent app tray your app gets terminated ( similar to Force Stop). And due to this every task running in the background like Services, Jobs gets killed with the app. Even High priority FCM doesn’t see the daylight in Chinese ROMs

> Real time problems :

1) You can’t fetch location of the user. So, no app would work properly if it depends on real-time location

2) You can’t recevie the FCM high priority notifications

3) No time specific task/Job would execute if app is not in the tray and many more ….

> Solution

user needs to enable auto start in settings for app to keep background service/Job running.By default it is off.To do this in some of the devices we can use,

Sample code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;

    switch (manufacturer) {

        case "xiaomi":
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter",
                    "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            break;
        case "oppo":
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                    "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));

            break;
        case "vivo":
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager",
                    "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
            break;
    }

  List<ResolveInfo> arrayList =  getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
          PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

}
```

[SOURCE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52849445/some-oreo-devices-are-not-getting-push-notification/52943903#52943903](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52849445/some-oreo-devices-are-not-getting-push-notification/52943903#52943903)

Comment: Superb answer! Worked like awsome. One question, is there a way to allow app to run in the background without prompting the user to enable it manually?

Comment: No this is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to Settings>More settings>Permission management(Applications) > Autostart to turn on the app switch.

Comment: Nice! My problem was resolved on Vivo V9. Thanks for your help.