# React native Fire base Push notification not working in OPO,VIVO, MI when app is close

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

Fire base push notification is not working when app Killed or force stop in Mi, Vivo, OPPO.In my code, android firebase push notification is working fine in Moto g4 and Samsung, but it's not working in Mi, Vivo, OPPO when app is killed. But it's working when autoStart on. That means the background service killed if the app is autostart off. How can I solve this issue?

I already tried like following link [oppo, vivo app kill notification not coming in android fcm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128552/oppo-vivo-app-kill-notification-not-coming-in-android-fcm). But it opens the settings and user needs to switch on option. However, I need automatically on that.

Comment: which lib you are using for notification? i am using react-native-firebase and its working in all three of phones Oppo,Vivo,MI

Comment: react-native-firebase push notification, but my side is not working, its working in samsung.

Comment: if you don 't mind can i have your skype id?